# Returning multiple sql query results - C#

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-3.0

I have following method which runs about 20 sql queries. What is the best way to return back the results to client?

```
public int Results()
{
    using (var conn = GetConnection())
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT TOP 1 stdent_number from Students";

                conn.Open();
                var result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT TOP 1 class_number from Classes";
        var number = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT TOP 1 table from Tables";
        var table = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT TOP 1 suite from Suites";
        var suite = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                 .....
                //I want to return result, number, table and suite so they can be populated on client
        //What is the best way to return? Should I create IEnumerable and add values to it and return
        //as IEnumerable or should these be returned all separately or as a dictionary?
        //Also this is just an example in real time I have at least 15 values from sql queries that I       //want to return

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to create a proc then try like below

Pass all your queries in to string variable like below...

```
string sql = "SELECT TOP 1 stdent_number from Students; SELECT TOP 1 class_number from Classes; SELECT TOP 1 table from Tables; SELECT TOP 1 suite from Suites";
```

after that try like below..

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    var result,number,table;
    conn.Open();
            Cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlDataReader sqlReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                result = dr[0].ToString();
            }

            sqlReader.NextResult();

            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                number = dr[0].ToString();
            }

            sqlReader.NextResult();

            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                table = dr[0].ToString();
            }

            sqlReader.Close();
            Cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
}
```

Also Try this link : [Return multiple set](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/ExecutingaQueryThatReturnsMultipleResultSetswithSqlDataReader.htm)

Comment: Pandian - Actually we are not looking to create a store proc. Is there any other better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly you need how to pass all successful queries data back to your client from this function.
I would suggest you to create your own classes (DTO's [Data Transfer Objects]) to pass the multiple information to Client from your function.Instead of Using a Return Type of function of Int.